# 4th Order Linear Homogeneous Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please solve the following Differential Equation:

$y''''+2y'''-9y''-10y'+50y=0$

I am unable to find roots of its auxiliary equation.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I try to find root's of the auxiliary equation by choosing divisors of 50 but none of them  satisfy the equation.

Comment: None of the roots are real.

Comment: Try factoring it into two quadratics. Then you can apply quadratic formula on both factors.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $r^4+2r^3-9r^2-10r+50=(r^2-4r+5)(r^2+6r+10)$